# Should this site be under "Culture / Recreation" rather than "Life / Arts"?

Tags: discussion, stackexchange

I was wondering about all those questions about world building in here, that would be better off in Worldbuilding. Why do people come here posting those instead of going to Worldbuilding directly?

And then, quite by accident, I noticed something in the list of sites below. Down there ↓.

The list is divided into several categories, *Technology*, *Life / Arts*, *Culture / Recreation*, *Science* and *Other*. And we are under *Life / Arts*, where you can find sites for gardeners, artists and crafters, musicians, photographers, writers etc. Worldbuilding is in the same category.

So maybe those people coming here are confused? Do they think this is a site for scifi writers?
My take is that this site would be better off in the category *Culture / Recreation*, which has sites about mythology, anime & manga, chess, role playing games etc.

What do you think?

Comment: I wonder where all the downvotes come from. Are people really disagreeing with suich a move; thinking we're better off among the scholars, artists and crafters,  professionals, specialists etc, than among the enthusiasts, the fans, skeptics, afficionados and so on? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 4):

This isn't a feature that can be implemented via a decision here. You'll need to raise it on the [main meta site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/).

For the record, I think that this is an irrelevance. These sorts of low quality worldbuilding questions are generally a result of people **not reading the [tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour) and [FAQ](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help) before they decide to post their off-topic questions on our site** rather than a misunderstanding caused by the header over a gateway that almost no-one uses.

Comment: For the record, that list of sites down in the footer of every page was how I first discovered SFF.SE.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - And did the fact that it was under LIFE / ARTS rather than CULTURE / RECREATION encourage you to post blatantly off-topic questions?

Comment: No, I don't recall noticing the headers at all, and in any case I lurked for long enough that I already had a pretty good idea of what kind of questions were considered OK here before I signed up. I was just responding to the last few words of your answer.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - Perhaps I should have said "a gateway that almost no-one *sensible* uses" :-)

Comment: @Randal'Thor - [Rule 33](https://archive.org/stream/RulesOfTheInternet/RulesOfTheInternet..txt) always applies.